# No value accessor for form control with path : 'options -> tradeDate'

Tags: angular

I am unable to fix this spec file error which is coming when I run the mutation tests.

Hi, I am new to Angular, I have to make this spec file work but I am struggling to figure why I get this error.
No value accessor for form control with path : 'options -> tradeDate'

title .html file

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
<div class="container formArrayName="options">
<div class="box">
<div class"col *ngIf="isTradeDateVisible">
<div class="col">
<p>trade</p>
</div>
<div class ="radio-heading">
//custom selector
<sui-group-radiogroup
fromControlName="tradeDate"
[radioItems]="tradeRadioItems"
(selected)="onTradeDateSelected($event)">
</sui-group-radiogroup>
</div>
</div>
<div class"col *ngIf=isBuyMethodVisible">
<div class="col padding">
<p>radio button2</p>
</div>
<div class ="radio-heading">
<sui-group-radiogroup
fromControlName="tradeDate"
[radioItems]="tradeRadioItems"
(selected)="onTradeDateSelected($event)">
</sui-group-radiogroup>
</div>
</div>
</form
```

//few more div are there I did not add it here
title component.ts file

```
import {component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Controlcontainer,FormBuilder,FromGroup,FormGroupDirective} from '@angular/forms';

@component({
//added whatever is needed 

})

export class TitleComponent implements OnInit {
@Input() radioItems1 :any;
@Input() radioItems2 :any;
@Input() form: FormGroup;

isTradeDateVisible :boolean;
isBuyMethodVisible :boolean;

constructor()
{
}
ngOnInit(); void{
this.isTradeDateVisible = true;
this.isBuyMethodVisible = false;
}

onTradeDateSelected(data: number) {
if(data === 0){
this.isTradeDateVisible = true;
this.isBuyMethodVisible = false;
}
if(data === 1){
this.isTradeDateVisible = true;
this.isBuyMethodVisible = true;
}
}

onBuyMethodSelected(data: number) {
this.isTradeDateVisible = true;
this.isBuyMethodVisible = true;
}
}
```

title-spec file

```
import { CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';
import { componentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { FormBuilder,FormsModule,ReactiveFormsModule} from '@angular/forms';
import { TitleComponent } from './TitleComponent';

describe('TitleComponent',() => {
let component: TitleComponent;
let fixture: ComponentFixture<TitleComponent>;
let formBuilder : FromBuilder;

beforeEach(async ()=> {
await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
declarations: [TitleComponent],
schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA],
imports: [FormsModule,ReactiveFormsModule],
providers: [FormBuilder],
}).compileComponents();
});

beforeEach() =>{
fixture = TestBed.createComponent(TitleComponent);
component= fixture.componentInstance;
formBuilder = TestBed.inject(FormBuilder);
component.form = fromBuilder.group({
options: formBuilder.group({
tradeDate: '',
buyMethod: '',
}),
transactions: {},
}); //options will be added in front of transactions array , nested forms
fixture.detectChanges();
});

if('should create',() =>{
expect(component).toBeTruthy();
});
});
```

TradeComponent.ts file

```
export class TradeComponent implements onInit{
form : FromGroup;

radioItems1 :any;  
radioItems2 :any;

constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
this.form = this.fb.group({
options: this.fb.group({}),
transactions: this.fb.array([]),
});
}

ngOnInit(): void {


this.radioItems1 =[
{
inputLabel: "something",
inputValue:"else",
},
inputLabel: "nothing",
inputValue:"else",
},
];

this.radioItems2 =[
{
inputLabel: "hello",
inputValue:"hi",
},
inputLabel: "welcome",
inputValue:"hello",
},
];
this.setTransactionTitleFromGroup();
}


get titles(): FormGroup()
{
return this.form.get('options') as FormGroup;
}


setTransactionTitleFromGroup()
{
const _titlesArray =[
'tradeDate',
'buyMethod',
];

_titlesArray.forEach(option)=> {
this.titles.addControl(option, new FormControl());
});
}
}
```

Comment: Before we can possibly help you, you have to fix the code to the point where it's readable and valid. I tried to format but there's a lot broken with it, it's not even valid (syntax errors, invalid constructs, etc.)

Comment: I am sorry, I could not copy the code I had to type eveything. I will try to fix this

Comment: Please check I have fixed few things

Answer (score 0):

```js
beforeEach() =>{
  fixture = TestBed.createComponent(TitleComponent);
  component= fixture.componentInstance;
  formBuilder = TestBed.inject(FormBuilder);
  component.form = fromBuilder.group({
    options: formBuilder.group({ // <-- options is a group
      tradeDate: '',
      buyMethod: '',
    }),
    transactions: {},
  }); //options will be added in front of transactions array , nested forms
  fixture.detectChanges();
});
```

Your test fixture is creating a form that's not in the expected form. `options` is expected to be an array as indicated by the `formArrayName="options"` attribute in your template.

```html
<form [formGroup]="form">
  <div class="container formArrayName="options"> <!-- <-- options is an array -->
    <div class="box">
    ...
```

The form and template must match for it to work.

You probably intended to make it a group, so change the `formArrayName` attribute to `formGroupName`. Then fix the other issues with the rest of the code.

Comment: I have changed it to formGroupName. 
<form [formGroup]="form">
  <div class="container formGroupName="options"> <!-- <-- options is an array -->
    <div class="box">. But the error still persists when I run the mutation test. 
no value accessor for form control with path options tradedate.

Comment: I have changed it to formGroupName.  ````<form [formGroup]="form"> <div class="container formGroupName="options"> <!-- <-- options is an array --> <div class="box">. ````But the error still persists when I run the mutation test. no value accessor for form control with path options tradedate.